# Small mottled beetle identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I live in Chapel Hill, North Carolina, and recently started seeing a bunch of these little guys in my house. They're about 1/8" long (estimate), with brown/black zigzag stripes; it's possible they're babies, but over the last two weeks their size has remained consistent so this seems unlikely.

[image: What is this?]

Comment: Related: [What's this black, white and orange beetle?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/57919/16866)

Answer (score 6):

It's probably an adult [varied carpet beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varied_carpet_beetle) (*Anthrenus verbasci*). They are quite small and commonly found in homes. Here's one of a number of images available on Wikimedia:

[image]

Comment: You'll likely come across more of their larvae than the adults themselves. Their larvae are often found munching on organic matter throughout the home (e.g., bedding, clothing, organic crafts, hair or crumbs in cracks, dead mice in walls, etc.). See the following images showing [relative size](http://www.whatsthatbug.com/wp-content/uploads//2010/02/carpet_beetle_larvae_jen.jpg), [actual size](http://www.whatsthatbug.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/carpet_beetle_larvae_florida.jpg), and a [zoomed-in view](http://msue.anr.msu.edu/uploads/images/5-21varied%20carpet%20beetle%20larva.jpg) of larvae.

Comment: You can contact SE for help fixing this here: http://biology.stackexchange.com/contact