# What's this black, white and orange beetle?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, pest-control

[image]

Found in Toronto Canada.
Maybe 1-2 mm long but I'm not a good judge of measurements.
Should I be concerned it has friends? I've dealt with carpet beetle larvae in several homes over 7 years and an praying this isn't an adult.

Comment: Rulers are good judges of measurement ;)

Comment: [Related, but no real duplicate (different species).](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42072/small-insect-identification/42074#42074)

Answer (score 15):

Yes this is an adult carpet beetle.

Specifically,  this is a **Common carpet beetle** (*Anthrenus scrophulariae*)

[image: carpet beetle]

See [here](http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/fabric/common_carpet_beetle.htm) for more info.

- 2.5 to 3.8 mm in length.
- Black head (mostly hidden by the prothorax) + black  thorax and elytra with distinct scale patterns.

  - The thorax is covered with white scales except for a large midline.
  - The elytra have orange to red scales down the midline with variable patches of white scales.

    - Note: in older individuals, some or all of the scales may be lost and the color pattern may look different.

This species is found worldwide.

Unlike the larvae,  the adults are primarily pollen grazers.