# Tiny bug in Amman-Jordan

Tags: species-identification, entomology, species, pest-control

[image][image][image][image]

I saw this bug many times in my room this spring. Can any one help identifying it?!

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of [Small mottled beetle identification](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42072/small-mottled-beetle-identification/42074); the species involved is a widely distributed pest.

Comment: Is it dangerous? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Not so much dangerous as a nuisance; the question I've linked to has an answer that eventually links to web pages that discuss control measures.